# Preferred User Tagging for questions

Tags: feature-request

Doesn't anyone think that it would be nice if someone could tag a preferred SO user whom they would like to get involved to answer a question if they have such a user available? Such that if I had a question which I want answered, I could tag a user whom I know would be of great help and they would be notified to view the question and answer it if they could.

Comment: I'm pretty sure popular users would be pretty annoyed by such _feature_ :P ...

Comment: Some of those users are monitoring tags they are interested in.  For example Mark Gravell and Protobuf-net related questions.  A question is not necessarily Erik Lippert-worthy just because you tag it so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah, I see your point. Okay, I concur.

Comment: _@Peter_ _"Okay, I concur. "_ Ask [@JonSkeet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) what he would think about such feature.

Comment: Closing this as unclear is a bad joke. Tried to find a duplicate, but there seem to be none left...

Comment: Haha, no need, I didn't really think of it from the tagged user's perspective. I really wouldn't want to have to keep track of countless tags...

Comment: someone tried to do this not long ago.  they posted an insipid question, then a few minutes later added a comment: `@JonSkeet @HansPassant @SLaks ...` and 2 others.

Comment: @Plutonix I was of the thought that whoever was tagging the other users at least knew what they were doing, not any more

Comment: This feature does work really well in places like github for example, where a particular user is very likely to want to be included in a discussion and folks know it.  On here, I always want to include Robert Kern for example in any question about Enthought libraries, but as others have stated, it just doesn't scale well to SO's model.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Doesn't anyone think that it would be nice if someone could tag a preferred SO user whom they would like to get involved to answer a question if they have such a user available?"*

What makes you think you have *"such a user available"*?

Well, most of the users here (at least those having a higher rep upon some of the particular language or niche question tags) work with using filters for the question tags, they are actually interested in (as I do with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag).

I don't think any popular users that frequently answer niche tag questions would be very pleased to see a 100 or more notifications a day, to check questions that apply to their (assumed) field of experience.

There's no need for such a *call in* feature here IMHO.